# $X_n \to X$ a.s. iff $\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_n \, \, \text{i.o.})=0$ for some $\epsilon_n \to 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I know that $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. $\leftrightarrow$ $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon\ \text{i.o.})=0$ for all $\epsilon>0$.

> My question is : If we show $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_n\ \text{i.o.})=0$ such that $\epsilon_n$ goes to zero, can we conclude that $X_n$ converges to $X$ almost surely? How about the converse?

I've seen that by $P(|X_n-X|>\frac{1}{n}\ \text{i.o.})=0$ people conclude that $X_n$ converges to $X$ a.s., but I'm not sure about a general $\epsilon_n$.

Answer (score 1):

If $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|> \epsilon_n \, \, \text{i.o.}) = 0, \tag{1}$$ then $X_n \to X$ almost surely. This follows simply from the fact that $(1)$ means that for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$ we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\omega \notin \{|X_n-X|>\epsilon_n\} \quad \text{for all $n \geq N$,}$$ i.e. $$|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)| \leq \epsilon_n \quad \text{for all $n \geq N$.}$$ As $\epsilon_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ we get $\lim_{n \to \infty} |X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|=0$.

The converse does in general not hold true, i.e. $X_n \to X$ almost surely does in general not imply $(1)$ for an **arbitrary** sequence $\epsilon_n \to 0$. Consider for instance $X_n := 2/n$ and $\epsilon_n = 1/n$, then $X_n \to X=0$ almost surely but $$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X|> \epsilon_n \, \, \text{i.o.}) = 1.$$
However, if $X_n \to X$ a.s. then we can always find a sequence  $\epsilon_n \to 0$ such that $(1)$ holds. Indeed: As $X_n \to X$ almost surely we have

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \geq N} |X_n-X| \geq \epsilon \right) \xrightarrow[]{N \to \infty} 0$$

for any $\epsilon>0$. Choosing $\epsilon = 1/k$ for fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$ this means that there exists $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \geq N_k} |X_n-X| \geq \frac{1}{k} \right) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $ N_1 < N_2 < \ldots$. Applying the Borel-Cantelli lemma we find that

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \geq N_k} |X_n-X| \geq \frac{1}{k} \, \, \text{for infinitely many $k$} \right)=0.$$

If we define

$$\epsilon_n := \frac{1}{k} \qquad \text{for} \, \, N_k \leq n < N_{k+1}, k \in \mathbb{N}$$

then this shows

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_n-X| \geq \epsilon_n \, \, \text{i.o.})=0.$$

Comment: You gave a counter example for a specific sequence of $\epsilon_n$. Is there a sequence of $\epsilon_n$ such that $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_n i.o.)=0$?

Comment: @S_Alex For the particular example which I gave you can answer this question yourself, can't you?

Comment: I want to construct a sequence $1,...,1,\frac{1}{2},....,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{3},....$. But I'm not sure exactly when to switch from $1$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{3}$, etc

Comment: @S_Alex Not sure what you are talking about... you could simply put e.g. $\epsilon_n := 3/n$

Comment: I'm talking about the general case. When $X_n$ is a general random sequence and it converges to $X$ almost surely. Then we can find a sequence $\epsilon_n$ such that $P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon_n \ i.o.)=0$ and $\epsilon_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @S_Alex See my edited answer... note that it is not clear from your question that it is unclear what you mean by "the converse". There are several statements which you might consider as "the converse".